# How to interpret .get_booster().get_score(importance_type='weight') for XGBRegressor()

Tags: regression, feature-selection, xgboost

I am trying to do feature selection using XGRegressor(). I am doing this because I have many features to choose from over 4,000. Once I have a set of features I have a neural network I created to use these features to predict median_gross_rent.

My question is the following, I have these feature important scores from

```
feature_important = model.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')
keys = list(feature_important.keys())
values = list(feature_important.values())

feat_imp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=keys, columns=["score"]).sort_values(by = "score", ascending=False)
```

[image]

Is there a threshold score that I should set to make a cutoff? What are the best practices for feature selection in determining out of large amount of features to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must select features in this way, the traditional method is **to pick the number of top features** that you want to obtain, instead of a threshold.

Normally this kind of feature selection is done only when there too many features with respect to the number of instances. This is why one tries to guess what would be a reasonable number of features $n$, then arbitrarily pick this number. A slightly more advanced method is to try for several values of $n$, e.g. 100,200,300..., train/test a model for each $n$ (on a validation set), then observe how the performance evolves using these values in order to pick the best number.

Note that selecting feature based on their individual importance is not always optimal. When possible, it's better to let to the algorithm decide which features it uses.

Comment: Would you then suggest using all the features and just letting the algorithm to decide which one is important to use?

Comment: @Wolfy yes, you should at least try once with all the features so that you can compare if the performance is improved when you remove some of the features. the ideal scenario is to try to train a model with every possible subset of features, but that's almost never possible in practice.

Comment: Thank you for the response, any algorithms you would recommend using? I am using xgboost regression function for testing the data, but I was thinking of using the DNN Regressor from tensorflow. Any recommendation are much appreciated.

Comment: @Wolfy there's no way to know which algorithm will work better (especially without knowing the kind of task). I'm not knowledgeable about DNN so I don't have much opinion about it. However what I always recommend is to to start with a traditional method like decision trees, if only to be used as a baseline to compare against the more advanced methods. In terms of more advanced feature selection, genetic selection is often very good but it requires training/testing the model many times.